# Open Sets of lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology

So I know that sets of the form $(0,b)$ for $b<1$ are open in the $(0,1)_l,$ where $l$ denotes the lower limit topology. But my question is, why is the set say $(0,0.5)$ open in $(0,1)_l?$ Because from how I understand open sets, given any $a\in (0,0.5)$, we can find some $B_{\epsilon}(a)\subset (0,0.5)$.

Indeed this seems to be true, but what I have trouble seeing is that for any $x\in (0,1)_l,$ say $x=0$, then $x \notin B_{\epsilon}(a)\subset (0,0.5)$.

My question is, if we choose some $x$ in the set $R$ where the set $U$ is open in, does it have to hold $\forall x \in R$, such that $x\in B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset U$ and $x \in U?$

Comment: What is $B_\varepsilon(a)$?

Comment: That is the open ball with respect to $a \in U$, with $\epsilon >0.$

Comment: Ball?! With respect to what distance?

Comment: So basically it is $|x-a|<\epsilon$, where $x,a\in U$ with $a $ fixed , in the lower limit topology. I am sorry I dont think I can make it any clearer from the knowledge that I have at this point in time.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot tell me what the set $B_\varepsilon(a)$ is? And what does it mean to add “in the lower limit topology” to the end of the sentence?

Comment: I feel like you've misread some notation and $B$ should be a basis element instead of a ball.

Comment: Ok I think I am mixing up the topological definition of open sets, and metric spaces. From this question I am referring to the metric space defintion of open sets.

Comment: I'm confused by your question in the last sentence. I think you've maybe worded something in a way that you didn't intend. Are you asking if for all $x \in R$ there exists a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U$?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. But in the metric space, if we do fix some point $a \in U$ so that $|x-a|<\epsilon$, will this hold $\forall x\in R?$

Comment: No, it's not true because $x$ might not even be in $U$. For instance if $U = (0,0.5)$ and $x = 0.6$. Is there a reason why you would expect this to be true? Also, you say in your OP that $x = 0$ is in $(0,1)_l$ but this is not true.

Comment: So for the set $U$ to be in some metric space $R,$ we only need some open ball to be in $U$ such that $x,a$ which are in $R$ are in $U$ only?

Comment: In a metric space a set $U$ is open if for all $x \in U$ there exists an open ball around $x$ that is contained in $U$. That is all. By the way, I don't think that $(0,1)_l$ is metrizable. That is, it is a topological space but I don't think it can be made into a metric space.

Comment: ok thank you for the clarification, I guess I will make the next post on how to determine open sets properly on a topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[x,y)$ is open in $(0,1)_l$ when $0<x<y<1.$ And $(0,0.5)=\bigcup_{(0<x<0.5)}[x,0.5).$

Comment: The notion of an "open ball" in $(0,1)_l,$  if  defined at all, should be used with caution, because the topology cannot be generated by  a metric.